# How to check for a value on a different table?

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 tables one called Exams and the other Exam Results. In the exam I enter the passing_score and in the Exam Results I save the answer of the exam. I'm trying to look up the passing_score and if the passing score is greater then the result then the person passed.

Here is the entire function of this code

```
public function exam($course_id, Request $request)
        {
            $course = Course::where('id', $course_id)->firstOrFail();
            $answers = [];
            $exam_score = 0;
            foreach ($request->get('question') as $question_id => $answer_id) {
                $question = ExamQuestion::find($question_id);
                $correct_answer = ExamOption::where('exam_question_id', $question_id)
                    ->where('id', $answer_id)
                    ->where('is_correct', 1)->count() > 0;
                $answers[] = [

                    'exam_question_id' => $question_id,
                    'exam_option_id' => $answer_id,
                    'corect' => $correct_answer
                ];
                if ($correct_answer) {
                    $exam_score += $question->score;
                }
            }

            $exam_result = ExamResult::create([
              'exam_id' => $course->exam->id,
              'employee_id' => \Auth::id(),
              'result' => $exam_score,
            ]);
            $exam_result->answers()->createMany($answers);

            $exam_id = ExamResult::all();

            $final_results = Exam::where('id', $exam_id)->get(['passing_grade']);
            $val = $final_results->passing_grade;


            if($exam_result->result >= $val) {
              $exam_result->is_complete = 1;
              $exam_result->save();
}

            return redirect()->route('learn.show', [$course, $request])->with('message', 'Test score: ' . $exam_score);
        }
```

Here is the logic I've tried and I get stuck.

```
  $exam_id = ExamResult::all();
  $final_results = Exam::where('id', $exam_id)->get('passing_grade');
  $val = $final_results->passing_grade;

            if($exam_result->result >= $val) {
              $exam_result->is_complete = 1;
              $exam_result->save();
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::columnize() must be
>   of the type array, string given, called in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/QuickHS/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php
>   on line 137

Here is the database structure for the 2 tables 
This is the exam table
[image]

This is the exam results table 
[image]

Comment: please post table schema

Comment: `$exam_id` should be a collection, so you can't do `Exam::where('id', $exam_id)` because it is expecting a number, a string or `null`. Then, where is declared `$exam_result`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correction. Please try this.

```
 $final_results = Exam::where('id', $exam_id)->first();
 $val = $final_results->passing_grade;
```

Comment: Thank you, however is not working. I get an error of Property [passing_grade] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: I have just update the answer. Please check it. I hope it should work.

Comment: Thank you, however is still not working I get the following error Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: You can try this. =>  $val = $final_results['passing_grade'];

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved it and here is how I did it

```
     $final_results= Exam::first();
     $x = $final_results->passing_grade;

      if($exam_result->result >= $x) 
        {
               $exam_result->is_complete = 1;
                  $exam_result->save();
   }
```